# How to call deriveFont() correctly after Font.createFont() in Java?

Tags: java, fonts

I want to resize a custom font to match my layout.
But sadly `font.deriveFont(128.0f);` has no effect at all. I already tried some hints I found but nothing helped yet.

The output of the `System.out.println(font)` equals to `java.awt.Font[family=Arial,name=Arial,style=plain,size=1]`

```
package main;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontFormatException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class FontTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        String fName = "fonts/arial.ttf";
        InputStream is = FontTest.class.getResourceAsStream(fName);
        
        Font font = null;
        
        try {
            font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
            font.deriveFont(128.0f);
        } catch (FontFormatException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        EmptyBorder padding_h1 = new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10);
        
        System.out.println(font);
        JLabel text = new JLabel("Hallo Welt!");
        text.setFont(font);
        text.setBorder(padding_h1);
        
        frame.add(text);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`font.deriveFont`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#deriveFont(float)) does not change `font`. Rather, it:

> **Creates a new `Font` object** by replicating the current Font object and applying a new size to it.

The newly created `Font` object is returned.

So just calling it like this:

```
font.deriveFont(128.0f);
```

will create a new `Font` object, and throw it away immediately, as you are not using the return value at all.

You can move the `deriveFont` call to where you need the new font:

```
text.setFont(font.deriveFont(128.0f));
```

Alternatively, actually change `font` by reassigning it:

```
font = font.deriveFont(128.0f);
```

Comment: immutable ohh fuuuu 
thank you very much kind sir
Edit: I will mark your question in a few minutes

Comment: yeah it is but you know the 10min lock before I can mark it as accepted :)